# Spring LogoutHandler: sendRedirect with 302 status

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring logoutSuccessHandler.
 when user logout, I redirect call to targetURL with status 302. here is my code to implement this:

```
  public class LogoutHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

public LogoutHandler(AuthenticationContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String targetUrl = "mytarget";

   authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
   response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);

    response.setHeader("Location", targetUrl);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
    response.getWriter().write(targetUrl);
    response.getWriter().flush();
    response.getWriter().close();

 }

}
```

but this code doesn't work and I have status canceled for this /logout webservice.
How could we implement lougoutHandler?

Comment: Why? What is it that the default does't do? If you want a different strategy, implement a custom `RedirectStrategy` and inject that, instead of extending the `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` and disabling that by completely overriding its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your custom [`LogoutSuccessHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html):

```
static class RedirectLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

    private String logoutUrl;
    private int statusCode;

    public RedirectLogoutSuccessHandler(String logoutUrl, int statusCode) {
        this.logoutUrl = logoutUrl;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(statusCode);
        response.setHeader("Location", logoutUrl);
    }
}
```

And configure it using:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new RedirectLogoutSuccessHandler("http://www.google.com", HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY));
}
```

---

Or as @M.Deinum suggested use the `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` and inject a custom [`RedirectStrategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/RedirectStrategy.html):

```
static class CustomRedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String url) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
        response.setHeader("Location", url);
    }
}
```

and configure it:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    logoutSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("http://www.google.com");
    logoutSuccessHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new CustomRedirectStrategy());
    //...
    http
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);
}
```

Comment: when I try with the first method logout is not redirected to targetUrl (www.google.com ) and I get this error in browser:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: So you are initiating the logout from an XMLHttpRequest Context?
Both implementations above work when initiated using get/post (not from an ajax context).

Comment: in my case, I initiate the logout in ajax context with post /logout

Comment: In javascript/ajax context you probably need to implement the redirect by yourself (`window.location.href`...). But i would go with the "standard" approach.

Comment: It seems that your js-framework tries to follow the redirect (the external url) - which is a security risk - therefore you geht the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing - be aware that the target resource needs to setup the CORS header).

Comment: how can I setup this CORS header? I have already set my header as follow Access-Control-Allow-Origin :"*"

Comment: The target resource needs to add the CORS-header - so you need to be able to configure the target-server (if you want to redirect to a server you do not own - or cannot be configured to add your application-domain as a CORS-header - it will not be possible). Again: do not use ajax for the logout.

Comment: In angularJs application how can we do logout without Ajax call?

Comment: simply add a standard logout form to your page - just as you would do if you would implement a standard mvc application.

Comment: How can we add this logout in fontend side?

Comment: Adding it to your template?

Comment: what is means adding it to my template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring boot to specify the logout success url like below :-

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl(<Successful Login>)
                .failureUrl(<Unsuccessful Login>)
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl(<Your Success Logout URL >)
            ;

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().cacheControl();
        http.headers().contentTypeOptions().disable();
        http.addFilterBefore(crosFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to redirect my success logout to an external url for example www.google.com. I used this code http.logout()..logoutSuccessUrl(<Your Success Logout URL >) but it doesn't work. and thi browser I have canceled status for my logout call